# Using logic in listcols (ggplot2 edition)

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I am trying to produce a slightly different result from a `purrr::map` iteration depending on a condition. Say I have this code producing plots and storing them in a dataframe:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> -- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.3.1 --
#> v ggplot2 3.3.5     v purrr   0.3.4
#> v tibble  3.1.6     v dplyr   1.0.7
#> v tidyr   1.1.4     v stringr 1.4.0
#> v readr   2.1.0     v forcats 0.5.1
#> -- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() --
#> x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

plots <- iris |>
  group_by(Species) |>
  nest() |>
  mutate(plot = map(data, ~ {
    ggplot(.x) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Petal.Width))
  }))
```

Say I only wanted to the first plot (or Species == "setosa", whatever) to have a legend like so:

```
plots$plot[[1]]
```

[image]

Then subsequent plots would have no legend like so:

```r
plots$plot[[2]] +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Is there anyway to do that directly in the `mutate`/`map` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cur_group_id()` to identify the current group. There are also other helper functions like `cur_group()`, which could give you even finer control over the operations to be done within each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

plots <- iris |>
  group_by(Species) |>
  nest() |>
  mutate(plot = map(data, ~ {
    ggplot(.x) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Petal.Width)) + 
      if (cur_group_id() > 1L) guides(fill = "none")
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column `showlegend` to your nested data, use `map2` to loop over both `data` and `showlegend` and inside your plotting function remove the `legend` if `showlegend == FALSE`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

plots <- iris |>
  group_by(Species) |>
  nest() |>
  mutate(
    showlegend = Species == "setosa",
    plot = map2(data, showlegend, ~ {
      guide <- if (!showlegend) guides(fill = "none")
      ggplot(.x) +
        geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Petal.Width)) +
        guide
    })
  )

plots$plot[[1]]
```

[image]

```r
plots$plot[[2]]
```

[image]